# What's the probability that I will earn \$25?

Tags: probability

I go to a casino with \$100. At the casino, I play a game in which I get \$1 if I win, and lose \$1 if I lose. The probability of me winning is $\frac{1}{4}$, and I must either win or lose every time I play this game. I will keep playing this game until I either earn \$25 or lose all my money. What's the probability that I will earn \$25?

I originally thought that the answer was $\frac{1}{4^{25}}$ because I must win a net 25 times. However, I realized that the problem was far more complicated because I could win and lose many times. Furthermore, if I go broke, I must stop playing. What tools in probability can I latch off of to solve this problem?

Comment: You can use Markov chains to model this problem. Take a look at: http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath084/kmath084.htm

Comment: The right tool is suggested here. +1, Rod.

Comment: Hmm, thanks! I've heard the term "markov chain" before. It sounds worth learning about.

Comment: I was reading about Markov chains on Wikipedia, and they look really cool. All these states and weighted arrows going around... must I use Markov chains or could I use say some variation of the counting principle (like a decreasing geometric series)?

Comment: @DavidFaux: You have a total of $126$ states in your Markov chain. Make the $0$ state and the $125$ state *absorbing*, i.e., draw an arrow from themselves onto themselves, so that once you get to either $0$ or $125$, you stay there forever. They are sinks. Since you can play forever, at some point you should observe that probability is concentrating around the two sinks. To see this, build a $126 \times 126$ *tridiagonal* matrix that models this phenomenon and compute its 100th or 1000th power.

Comment: @RodCarvalho Actually one can compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n$ exactly. The exact probability is $$ p = \frac{608266787714075607107376692496241000}{51537752073261959782417520537272864939460
   3763001} \approx 1.18 \cdot 10^{-12} $$

Comment: @Sasha: Nice big fraction! Are you using arbitrary-precision rational numbers to compute $p$? Did you compute the Jordan canonical form of matrix $P$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $p_n$ be the probability that starting out with $n$ dollars you will reach $\$125$ before you reach $\$0$. Then we have the recurrence

$$
p_n=\frac14p_{n+1}+\frac34p_{n-1}
$$

for $0\lt n\lt125$ and the boundary conditions $p_0=0$ and $p_{125}=1$. The characteristic equation of the recurrence is

$$
\frac14\lambda^2-\lambda+\frac34=0
$$

with solutions $\lambda=1$ and $\lambda=3$. Thus the general solution is

$$
p_n=c_1+c_23^n\;,
$$

and the boundary conditions yield $c_1+c_2=0$ and $c_1+c_23^{125}=1$, with solution $c_2=-c_1=1/(3^{125}-1)$, so

$$
p_n=\frac{3^n-1}{3^{125}-1}
$$

and

$$
p_{100}=\frac{3^{100}-1}{3^{125}-1}\approx3^{-25}\approx1.18\cdot10^{-12}\;,
$$

as given by Sasha in a comment.

Comment: I think I can get $p_n=\frac14p_{n+1}+\frac34p_{n-1}$ by summing conditional probabilities. How do you get $\frac14\lambda^2-\lambda+\frac34=0$ from that? Furthermore, how do you get $p_n=c_1+c_23^n$?

Comment: @David: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence#Linear_homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

I can play 25 games (win all) or play 27 games (win 26, lose 1) or play 29 (win 27, lose 2), ...

The probability of winning n games of k games played is $\binom{k}{n}(1/4)^n(3/4)^{k-n}$ so the total probability should be
\begin{align}
\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\binom{25+2x}{x}(1/4)^{25+x}(3/4)^{x}
\end{align}
However this does not account for the fact that you can lose all your money for larger numbers of games played or you can overshoot \$25 so it is an upper bound: $2.3604707743147794*10^{-12}$

Comment: This also overcounts somewhat in situations where you reach $25$ before you play the last game of the sequence (e.g. If you win the first $25$ games, lose one, then win one, you're counting it both as winning $25$ and as winning $26$ of the first $27$)

Comment: @kevin darn, I forgot about that

Comment: Interestingly, my answer is about two times @Sasha 's answer (in the comment on the main post). Is this a coincidence?

Comment: What your answer computes is the expected number of times you are exactly 25 dollars ahead, ignoring the bankroll issues.  Now suppose that at some point you reach +25.  If you work through a similar argument to Joriki's recurrence relation, you'll see you have a $1/2$ chance of hitting +25 again given that you start from there.  So the expected number of times you hit 25, given you hit it at least once, is $1+1/2+1/4+\dots=2$.  This means your answer is exactly twice the correct answer to the infinite bankroll version.  And the infinite and 100 dollar versions have almost the same answer.

Comment: @KevinCostello Nice explanation.

Comment: @Navin: You can get the exact value for an infinite bankroll using the formula (25/(k+25))*C(2k+24,k)*.25^(25+k)*.75^k, summing from k = 0 to infinity, to get an ans of 1.1802e-12

Answer (score 1):

You have a $1$-dimensional [random walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk) where you jump forward with probability $1/4$ and backward with probability $3/4$.

Let $X_k$ be a random variable that denotes the amount of money you have after $k \geq 0$ games. You start with 100 dollars, so $X_0 = 100$ with probability equal to $1$, i.e., there is no uncertainty about the initial state so $\mathbb{P} (X_0 = 100) = 1$. Since you lose 1 dollar with probability $3/4$ and win a dollar with probability $1/4$, we have that $\mathbb{P} (X_1 = 99) = 3/4$ and $\mathbb{P} (X_1 = 101) = 1/4$. To obtain the probability mass function for $k \geq 2$, use the matrix formulation of Markov chains

$$\pi_{k+1}^T = \pi_k^T P$$

where $\pi_0$ is the probability vector whose $100$-th component is one and the rest are zero. Matrix $P$ is tridiagonal. You want to compute $\pi_{\infty}^T = \pi_0^T P^{\infty}$. Make the end states *absorbing* or *sinks*, which is to say that the diagonal of $P$ will be $(1,0,\dots,0,1)$. For more information, take a look at [this book](http://pages.uoregon.edu/dlevin/MARKOV/).